# How can I take a screenshot from all monitors with screencapture or other tools?

Tags: display, screen-capture

I wanted to use `screencapture` to take a screenshot of all monitors from within a script, but this only seems to capture the main monitor. How can I use `screencapture` or any other tool callable from the command line to capture all monitors?

Comment: I've edited your question to keep it (and potential answers) within the scope as defined in the [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's poorly documented, but it is indeed possible with the `screencapture` command.

```
screencapture ~/Desktop/screen1.png ~/Desktop/screen2.png [...]
```

Here's the relevant section from `man screencapture`:

```
 files   where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen
```

Of course, if you're calling it programmatically, you might not know how many monitors there are, so you'll have to parse the output of `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType` or `defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist` to determine how many filename arguments to pass to `screencapture`. For example:

```
$ system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep "Online: Yes" | wc -l
       2
```

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099333/terminal-command-to-show-connected-displays-monitors-resolutions
http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?p=695603

Comment: thanks.  I thought I tried with two filenames, but now it seems to work...

Comment: It looks like passing extra arguments doesn't hurt anything so you could always specify like 10 files and assume you'll never have more than that many monitors!